# Timestamped model __init__() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-extensions

I'm trying to create a foreignkey relationship in DRF models with an on_delete

```
fk_city = models.ForeignKey("region_mgmt.City", "warehouses", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)    
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'
```

below is my code:

```
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class State(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    fk_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name="states", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class City(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    fk_state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name="cities", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in another module I have the following model

```
class Warehouse(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    fk_city = models.ForeignKey("region_mgmt.City", "warehouses", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

does anyone know the reason and its solution?

Comment: You did not share the code with the `fk_city`...

Comment: But you should use `related_name='warehouses'`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @WillemVanOnsem I've added the missing code can you please have a look

Comment: The second positional argument to the `ForeignKey` constructor *must* be the `on_delete` parameter - you have supplied a second positional argument, as well as a keyword argument `on_delete`. You need to remove one. It seems like you intend for `warehouses` to be the related name, in which case you need to explicitly declare it as such using a keyword argument.

Comment: Thank you Yes I was missing the related_name keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of a `ForeignKey` is the [**`on_delete=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), so you specify two values for this. Likely you want to use your `warehouses` as [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), so you implement this as:

```
class Warehouse(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    # …
    fk_city = models.ForeignKey(
        'region_mgmt.City',
        related_name='warehouses',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
```